# Proper preposition for "absolve"

Tags: prepositions

Are you absolved *from* your sins or  absolved *of* your sins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preposition to use together *absolved* is *of*, or *from*.

> The pardon absolved them of any crimes.
>   She has been absolved from her promise to serve on the committee.

Similarly to the second sentence, I would write *from your sins*.

> I absolve you from your sins.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but <a href="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/absolve">dictionary.com</a> uses *from*...

Comment: I gave a partial answer; I need to expand it.

Comment: I don't recognise the use of 'absolve' in your second sentence.

Comment: I believe I've also heard it used without any preposition at all, putting the person as an indirect object: *I absolve you your sins.* This is commoner with *forgive*, though.

Comment: @Colin Fine: It means "release (from obligations / guilt)", so the "absolved from her promise" is fine (if rather unusual!).

Answer (score 2):

The word is very unusual outside a theological context, where the usual construction is 'absolve from', following the Latin.

Comment: The Latin in question being, e.g. _Ego te absolvo **a** peccatis tuis_ -- "I you (direct object) absolve _from_ sins your."

Comment: I am pleased to hear that exist a preposition which follow the Latin! +1

Comment: Well you could also be "absolved of" liability. So it is not necessarily true that it is unusual outside of religion.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that the Latin, too, uses the preposition, being as the prefix "ab" means "from". Does the preposition give the appearance of redundancy in both languages?

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to EL&U, Please note that this is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site, and from the answer that you have given, it's clear that it doesn't solve OP's problem. Answer box is only for those who know the exact answer, further if you have any more queries you can use the comment box once you get sufficient reputation. Please explore: http://english.stackexchange.com/help to know how things work here!