# Which is more suitable? from or of?

Tags: prepositions

I have a doubt regarding the correct preposition usage for the word *absolve*.

For example,

> The court has *absolved* him **from** all the charges leveled against him.

And another example,

> I *absolve* you **of** all your sins.

I googled for a bit and found this answer [Proper preposition for "absolve"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/proper-preposition-for-absolve) but the confusion remained.

Could someone tell me why the two prepositions have not been used interchangeably in these sentences? 
And are there any markers which can help one identify the correct preposition?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. (Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.) Here, the first two dictionaries I checked in had useful examples / usage notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used the same as freed.
Being free of or free from something has different connotations.

Free of something implies the thing in question is non-existent. ex, a house free of pests.
To be free from something is to have escaped it in some way, not implying the thing in question is suddenly gone. ex, free from their clutches.